OpenStreetMap base map is different from my download into QGIS
I have been using QuickOSM to input street and building data into QGIS however I am having some trouble. I have been using the OSM Standard base map and can see that the data I am getting from QuickOSM is different from the basemap data. I have tried downloading building data several times (using both the in area feature and the canvas extent feature) and it only downloads a few of the buildings shown on the basemap. Likewise when I download street data I want the width of the road to be reflected in my map but the layer is line rather than a polygon.
Is there anyway to adjust for these issues?

i find the data can lag from the tiles, the latest exports can be downloaded https://download.geofabrik.de/ (24 hours updates) example https://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/colorado.html

This worked thank you so much!
